# Вместо POST запроса отправляется GET хотя явно указан POST ( ajax )

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, get

Имеется простой запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
     $.ajax({
         method: 'POST',        
         url: '/admin/task/first_launch/'
     });
 });
```

Всё это дело на *Laravel*. Я создал маршрут для *POST* запроса, как положено. Но я получаю *ошибку 405* от сервера и в консоли явно видно, что отправляется *GET* запрос, причем когда я указываю *PUT*, то он отправляется. Пробовал `method: 'POST'` и `type: 'POST'`, не помогло.

В чём ошибка?

Comment: Покажите network в консоли браузера, возможно то-то ещё есть что вы упустили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему убрав слэш в конце адреса отправки. Хотя не понимаю почему не работало, т.к маршрут у меня  со слешем, но тем не менее помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Помогал решить такую же проблему коллеге, починил добавлением Content-Type в хедеры и исправлением протокола http на https